# CSS filters past viewport edges

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a [metaball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs) effect by blurring svg's (CSS Blur), then applying CSS contrast to the parent div to get hard edges back. Below is an example. For some reason, the filter does a weird thing on the edges.

I believe i would need to first extend the div to be bigger than the viewport, but some elements are dependent on VW and would therefore scale in an unexpected manner.. Anyone have an idea of how to expand the filter past the viewport edges?

[image]

Don't really know how to approach this, i would like the blur to extend past the viewport but retain current layout.

EDIT:
Needed to add white background to container div to make the contrast behave in the way i wanted. ( not go crazy on the viewport edges)

Comment: You need to change the thing in the one line ... that's about the amount of help we can provide with the current information. Edit the question, include a snippet that demonstrates the problem, then we have something to talk about.

Comment: Welcome! Would it be possible for you to provide a [mre] in a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?